# Creating Google Cloud Image fails with "Could not fetch resource: Internal error"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, redash

I'm trying to set up a private [Redash instance](https://redash.io/help/open-source/setup) with Google Cloud. Step 1 is to add the the Redash image to your account so you can boot a VM with it.

When adding the image through Google Cloud Shell, my shell times out before the process completes.

When adding the image through the Console UI, it loads and loads then disappears without a trace.

When adding an image through gcloud CLI, I finally get a response:

```
➜ gcloud compute images create "redash" --source-uri gs://redash-images/redash.8.0.0-b32245-1.tar.gz

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Internal error. Please try again or contact Google Support. (Code: '-527xxxxxxxxxx759')
```

<sup>(x = hidden number)</sup>

I have extremely slow internet, so I'm thinking this could potentially be the issue. I've contacted Google Support but no response.

Comment: Google had a networking problem earlier today. Retry to see if you were affected.

Comment: Yes that's correct. Google has a networking issue for which the status can be checked [here](https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/6PM5mNd43NbMqjCZ5REh). Kindly retry and see if you are able to add the image.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue or you are facing errors?

Comment: I wasn't able to resolve it at the time so I switched to AWS

Comment: I reproduced and executed the command `gcloud compute images create "redash" --source-uri gs://redash-images/redash.8.0.0-b32245-1.tar.gz`. Even for me also it seems it is taking more time to execute, then I have killed it using CRTL + C but when I checked the Compute Engine > Images , a redash image is created with the same timestamp I had executed the command. With this experiment I assume that even though command is interrupted, the image creation may run in background. I suggest you to check the images section in Compute Engine once.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced and executed the command `gcloud compute images create "redash" --source-uri gs://redash-images/redash.8.0.0-b32245-1.tar.gz`. Even for me also it seems it is taking more time to execute, then I have killed it using CRTL + C but when I checked the `Compute Engine > Images` , a redash image is created with the same timestamp I had executed the command. With this experiment I assume that even though command is interrupted, the image creation may run in background. I suggest you to check the images section in Compute Engine once.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of Redash's GCP account payment status.
If this issue reproduced, I recommend to tell redash admin to check their GCP account payment status.

The following URL talks about this issue with the Redash community.
https://discuss.redash.io/t/cant-pull-redash-image-on-google-cloud/9486